# Initialise a QGLWidget with a glClearColor

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8, qglwidget

I have a `QMainWindow` with a `QGLWidget` in it. I want the widget to display a 'clear' colour of my own choice, instead of the default black screen.

```
void MyQGLWidget::initializeGL(void) {
    glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
}

void MyQGLWidget::paintGL(void) {       
     qDebug("Painting grey-ness");
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     // ... Do more stuff, but only after a certain event has happened ...
}
```

This works, and I noticed that the method is called 4 times during the start-up. However, I only want to paint it blank once in the `paintGL()` method, because this method is being called very often after the start-up, and there actually is small but significant performance loss if the buffers are cleared at every call.

So I changed the code to this:

```
void MyQGLWidget::paintGL(void) {
    static bool screenOnBlank = false;
    if (!screenOnBlank) {
         qDebug("Painting grey-ness");
         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         screenOnBlank = true;
     }

    // ... Do more stuff, but only after a certain event has happened ...
}
```

Now the clearing is only done once, but I am left with a black screen, rather that with the grey screen of `glClearColor`. Why is this? Why does QGLWidget paint my screen black again? And more importantly, how can I make sure the screen is my own default colour, without repainting it blank at every time step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

In most platforms, the state of your backbuffer is *undefined* after performing a buffer swap. You can find more details [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7316/what-is-the-contents-of-the-buffer-after-a-call-to-glswapbuffers). Hence, you cannot rely on the behaviour that your buffer remains as you left it before the swap operations. Then, to ensure your program is cross-platform, you **have no other choice** than calling `glClear()` at each drawing.

**In practice:**

It is possible that your platform/configuration do guarantee that your buffer is unchanged, or don't guarantee it but it is still the case in practice. If you know you are in those cases after experimenting (see below), but still have your screen turned black, it means that somehow in your code, you did something "wrong" that makes Qt explicitly call `glClear()` with its own `glClearColor()`.

You can use this code to see if the buffer remains unchanged after swapBuffers(). It is actually the case in my configuration: Qt 4.8 on Linux 64bits:

```
// -------- main.cpp --------

#include <QApplication>
#include "GLWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    GLWidget * w = new GLWidget();
    w->show();
    return app.exec();
}


// -------- GLWidget.h --------

#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QTimer>


class GLWidget: public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget() : i(0), N(60)
    {
        timer.setInterval(16);
        connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), 
              this, SLOT(animationLoop()));
        timer.start();
    }


protected:
     void initializeGL()
     {
         glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     }

     void resizeGL(int w, int h)
     {
         glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)w, (GLint)h);
     }

     void paintGL()
     {
         bool test = false;
         if(i<N)
         {
             if(test)
                 glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
             glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         }
         else
         {
             if(test)
             {
                 glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
             }
         }
     }

private slots:
    void animationLoop() 
    {
         i++;
         if(i>2*N) i=0;
         updateGL();
    }

private:
    int i, N;
    QTimer timer;
};
```

1. if `test == true`, then I always call `glClearColor()` followed by `glClear()`, but alternating between a red color and a green color every second. I indeed see the color switching back and forth between red and green.
2. if `test == false`, then I only call `glClearColor()` once and for all in `initializeGL()`. Then in `paintGL`, I alternate between calling `glClear()` or not calling it. The screen stays red, i.e. never turns black (or display a unicorn) even when `glClear()` is not called.

Hence, regarding your problem:

1. Either your configuration is different than mine (the implementation of swapBuffers is provided by Qt and differs according to the underlying window system)
2. Or your code is broken.

Simple way to check: compile my code, and see if it still reproduces the issue. If it does, then you are in case 1., and there is nothing you can do about it (can be considered a bug of Qt, of rather an inconsistency, since the correct behaviour is not specified anywhere in the documentation). Otherwise, you are in case 2., and then you should provide more of your code so we could determine where is the issue.

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately incorrect. I tried it but it makes no difference.

Comment: And what if you try `setAutofillBackground(false)` in the constructor of your `QGLWidget`? If this doesn't work, then you have no other choice than to clear the buffer at each `paintGL`. Note that the performance hit shouldn't be an issue, this is what any highly optimized game do anyway. ;-)

Comment: Also that doesn't work, I'm afraid. I know that even in optimised games the glClear function is being called, but I've got heavy simulations running in the background, so any small reduction in overhead is worth it.

Comment: And I guess the more philosophical question "Why does this not work?" still remains in any case. ;-)

Comment: @Jelle: I think OpenGL doesn't guarantee you that the backbuffer remains unchanged after swapBuffer() is called. Hence, even though it could have worked in your configuration, you can't rely this behaviour. Hence, the answer is: either Qt do perform a clear itself with a black color, or simply you configuration does not preserve the previous pixels.

Comment: Finally, if your simulation is running on the CPU, this operation is a no-cost, since it runs asynchronously in the GPU, really this command just transfer a few bits to the GPU and let it do the job. Anyway, have you considered calling paintGL less often? To me it makes no sense not to clear if you draw things after. Are you doing operations in paintGL that are not GPU related?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I think you are right: I was wrong about the performance difference. There were slight changes, but the result wasn't very consistent. But as said, the underlying question remains. I also tried the following: `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); swapBuffers(); glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` so that both buffers would be grey, but to no avail. It just seems odd to me that Qt puts the screen on blank (i.e. black) even after the first `paintGL()` has already been called.

Comment: @Jelle Since I was still very surprised that you get the behaviour you get, I checked carefully the doc, and the conclusion is that it is nowhere specified that your buffers won't be erased by Qt, hence you can't rely on this behaviour and should call `glClear()`. However, I actually looked at Qt source code and you shouldn't get this behaviour. Hence I've coded a test to see how it behaves for me, and I can't reproduce your issue. See my edit and perform what's written in my last paragraph to narrow down your "underlying issue".

Comment: @Jelle See my edited post. I provide an actual definitive answer to your question. I mean, even the philosophical one.